# MySQL/CGI: password in C source file unsafe?

Tags: mysql, c

Is this line bad practice from a security stance?

```
connect = mysql_real_connect(connection, "host", "user", "password", "database", 0, (const char *)NULL, 0);
```

If so, what solution would you use?

**Edit**

```
void get_credentials(char* host, char* name, char* passwd, char* db) {
  char string_path[80] = "/etc/.acro";
  struct stat sb;
  stat(string_path, &sb);
  int file_OK = FILE_OK;
  if (sb.st_mode == 0644) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Corrupt login file: permissions");
    file_OK = FILE_BAD;
  }
  /* if(file_meta->st_uid != ???) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Corrupt login file: owner");
       file_OK = FILE_BAD;
     } */
  if(file_OK) {
    FILE *login_file = fopen(string_path, "r");
    fgets(host, 80, login_file);
    fgets(name, 80, login_file);
    fgets(passwd, 80, login_file);
    fgets(db, 80, login_file);
    host[strcspn (host, "\n")] = '\0';
    name[strcspn (name, "\n")] = '\0';
    passwd[strcspn (passwd, "\n")] = '\0';
    db[strcspn (db, "\n")] = '\0';
    fclose(login_file);
  }
}
```

**Edit 2**

The permission check should look like this for a 700 file:

```
// 33216 = 100700 in octal => rwx for owner only
if (sb.st_mode != 33216) { 
    printf("Corrupt login file: permissions");
    file_OK = FILE_BAD;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, for several reasons.

One, someone with read access to the binary could potentially run the `strings` command and look for likely possibilities near the phrase 'localhost'.

Two, if you ever decide to use the program elsewhere, you currently have the options of 1) setting up the exact same database on localhost with the exact same username and password (*really* unwise) or 2) altering the source code and recompiling for the second platform.

Alter the program to read its connection data from a config file in either `/etc/programname/program.conf` or `~/.programname/` depending on the flavor, and make it insist on having the directory permissions set to `700` and enforce proper ownership.

Comment: See the edit. I got server error if I took away the read rights. 644 was the lowest I got (on group and other). Also, I didn't understand what you said about ownership? (This is the commented region.)

Comment: By that I meant that the owner of the config file should be the same user that your program is going to run as -- IE, if it's a daemon running under the `nobody` user, then the file owner should be `nobody`; if it's going to be run on a per-user basis, it should check whether `~/.programname/` and `~/.programname/config` are owned by the user in question and set  to `0700` .

Comment: Also, it's considered exceptionally bad form to use 'hidden' directories in `/etc/`. Use `/etc/acro` instead.

Comment: It is a web interface that reads from a database. Right now, when I use my ordinary user and start a browser, and try, it crashes if the permissions of the login file are 0700 (not because of the check). It needs read rights, probably because of the fopen line. Or, will this be OK when I have the correct owner? And what should that be? Hidden: It is not a directory but a file, but OK, removed the dot.

Comment: If it's a web interface, it's likely running as the apache user -- run `ps axuf` while connecting via the browser and it should tell you what user the `httpd` process is running as.  That's the username you need to set the ownership to.

Comment: I didn't find any httpd with `ps axuf` - is this something that has to be monitored for a span of time? But, with `su -c "lsof -i | head -n 1 ; lsof -i | grep :http"` I found 10 files running the apache2 command: nine with user www-data, and one with root. Is that of use?

Comment: Yes. `www-data` is the user that apache switches to after it's connected to port 80, in order to keep itself going at reduced privelege. So that's the user you'd have to give ownership, or at least read access, to that file.

Comment: Yes, exactly right. Works with a 700 file now. Check out edit 2.

Comment: @Shadur, Since it's the apache user, how would an attacker go about getting read access to the binary?

Comment: @pacerier Through any number of potential security vulnerabilities in poorly written website code, or even unpatched vulnerabilities in the daemon itself. Check on the usual security sites for "remote execution exploits" or similar keywords. I just had to yell at a customer over a breakin like that the other day.

Comment: @Shadur, Hmm, if the attacker has already managed to enter the system, it's already game over right? What difference or additional benefits would your solution in the answer provide?